# Finding unique columns in an HDF5 dataset

Tags: python, c++, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm using `HDF5` to store very large data sets of `uint8s` (400 x 121000000). There is a huge amount of redundancy in the columns (97% of the columns are not unique). I need to merge duplicate columns efficiently. This means that I need to remove duplicate columns, while storing metadata to remember which columns were merged.

I am currently using Python with `h5py`, but if someone has an efficient C++ solution, I could simply use `boost::python` to implement it.

My current solution consists in loading blocks of the data set into a `NumPy` array and using a `dictionary` to store the unique columns and the metadata.

Note: the `HashableNDArray` class can be found [here](http://machineawakening.blogspot.ca/2011/03/making-numpy-ndarrays-hashable.html). I just renamed it.

```
def find_column_redundancy(dataset):
    n_columns = dataset.shape[1]
    block_size = 500000
    n_blocks = int(ceil(float(n_columns) / float(block_size)))

    d = {}
    analysed_column_count = 0
    for block in xrange(n_blocks):
        block_offset = block*block_size
        block_data = dataset[:, block_offset : block_offset+block_size]
        for i in xrange(block_data.shape[1]):
            hashable_array = HashableNDArray(np.ascontiguousarray(block_data[:, i]))
            d[hashable_array] = np.append(d.get(hashable_array, np.array([], dtype=np.int32)), block_offset + i)
            analysed_column_count += 1

    return d
```

Once I have iterated through all the columns, I return a `dictionary` that I use to write a new `HDF5` data set with the redundancy removed.

I need help; this can't be optimal!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say it's not optimal? Are you guessing there might be a better way, or are you dissatissfied with the memory/speed performance? My very first thought when I read the title was exactly what you did. Could this question possibly be more apppopriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Hi Reti43, thanks for your answer! At first, I was dissatisfied with the speed performance. This was taking ~18 hours on my laptop. My guess was that instantiating millions of HashableNDArrays was inevitably a bottleneck, but I did not know how to bypass it. I optimized my code and posted the solution below. Cheers! Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some profiling with [kernprof](https://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) and optimized my code.

- The biggest bottleneck was the instantiation of HashableNDArray objects. I found that by making the numpy arrays read-only, I could hash their data buffer without having to use the wrapper class. Also, extracting the buffer data as a string seems to allow for much faster hashing. To recover the column data, I use `np.frombuffer(dict_key, dtype=np.uint8)`.
- I also obtained a small speedup by replacing the dictionnary with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and eliminating the try/except block.
- Since my data only contains binary values, I found that using [np.packbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) on the columns allows to save memory by a factor of 8 when storing the keys and still allows to match identical columns. The only thing you need to remember to use [np.unpackbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) is the actual len of your columns, since numpy pads incomplete bytes with trailing 0.

Finally, I fine tuned the block_size to use the maximum amount of memory available. This allows for slightly longer disk reads and much better CPU usage.

This function used to run in ~18 hours on my data and it now runs in ~0.5 hours!

```
def find_column_redundancy(dataset):
    n_columns = dataset.shape[1]
    block_size = 10000000
    n_blocks = int(ceil(float(n_columns) / float(block_size)))

    d = defaultdict(list)
    analysed_column_count = 0
    for block in xrange(n_blocks):
        block_offset = block*block_size
        block_data = dataset[:, block_offset : block_offset+block_size]
        block_data = np.asfortranarray(block_data)
        block_data = np.packbits(block_data, axis=0)
        block_data.flags.writeable = False
        for i in xrange(block_data.shape[1]):
            d[block_data[:, i].data[:]].append(block_offset + i)
            analysed_column_count += 1

        print float(analysed_column_count)/n_columns*100, "% completed. Dictionnary has", len(d), "items."

return d
```

Comment: Wow, a factor of 36 improvement. Don't forget, you can mark your answer as the chosen one if it resolved your issue. ;)